# Variable is not printed csh

Tags: shell, csh

My Script :

```
current = `sqlplus -s $Schemaname/$password@$SID <<END
       set pagesize 0 feedback off verify off heading off echo off;
       select Count (*) from usr where activeuser='+';
       exit;
       END`

     set total = 1981

      echo $total
      echo $current

      set y = [ `expr 1981 - $current`] 

      echo $y
```

Console output :

```
1935
```

Expected Output :

```
1981
1935
46
```

Could you please help me to understand what went wrong here? apologies for not explaining clear earlier.

Comment: I have formatted your code, please check if I have made something wrong. Please read the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). Please also describe the expected result.

Comment: You have a mismatched backtick on the `count=...` line. It's hard to tell whether it was there in the original or not, since backticks are used for formatting.

Comment: I have modified my question, Please see the question.

Comment: I've re-edited your question. Part of your code (the "current=" part) was not being formatted as code.  Please confirm that my edit still reflects your intent.

Answer (score 0):

You can't combine a multiline inline input (e.g. `cat <<EOF`) with backtick syntax. The backticks must be on the same line.

The best you can do is [from original]:

```
#!/bin/tcsh -f

cat > /tmp/data <<END
set pagesize 0 feedback off verify off heading off echo off;
select Count (*) from user where activeuser='+';
exit;
END

set count="`sqlplus -s $schemaid$pwd@SID < /tmp/data`"

rm -f /tmp/data

set g = 44

echo $g
echo $count

set y = `expr $g - $count`

echo $y
```

---

**UPDATE:**

This isn't valid in `csh`:

```
#!/bin/tcsh -f
# badsyn

set val=`head -1 << EOF
abc
def
EOF`

echo "val is '$val'"
```

It produces a syntax error:

```
Unmatched `.
```

Here's your latest code with some annotations:

```
#!/bin/tcsh -f

# dummy variables
set Schemaname=foo
set password=bar
set SID=10

# BUG #1 -- csh needs a set command (i.e. "set current=" is correct but
# "current=" is a syntax error

# BUG #2 -- you want to capture the sqlplus output so you need to use
# backticks/virgules ("`") but they must be on the same line
current= sqlplus -s $Schemaname/$password@$SID <<END
           set pagesize 0 feedback off verify off heading off echo off;
           select Count (*) from usr where activeuser='+';
           exit;
           END

     set total = 1981

      echo $total
      echo $current

# BUG #3 -- the brackets aren't valid in csh here
      set y = [ `expr 1981 - $current`]

      echo $y
```

This can be done without using a temp file by using *two* scripts. Here's the first one:

```
#!/bin/tcsh -f
# fix2a

###set echo verbose

# dummy variables
set Schemaname=foo
set password=bar
set SID=10

set current="`./fix2b -s $Schemaname/$password@$SID`"

     set total = 1981

      echo $total
      echo $current

# BUG #3 -- the brackets aren't valid in csh here
      set y = `expr 1981 - $current`

      echo $y
```

Here's the second one:

```
#!/bin/tcsh -f
# fix2b

# dummy variables since I don't have sqlplus _or_ the database
alias sqlplus 'echo 1935 ; true'

sqlplus $argv <<END
           set pagesize 0 feedback off verify off heading off echo off;
           select Count (*) from usr where activeuser='+';
           exit;
        END
```

This is the output I get:

```
1981
1935
46
```

Comment: in My code , everything is working. The variable g and y is not printing. is there anything wrong with variable which i have defined ?

Comment: Post your complete code with exact syntax. Coincidentally, I wrote my first csh script in 1981 so I might be able to help ;-)

Comment: Craig, I have re posted my question for you. variables "total" and "y" are not getting printed in the console, what went wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Passing the password on the command line is a security risk.  Better to start SQL*Plus with /nolog and then use CONNECT.